# Dart version changes

Tags: flutter, version

Im getting the following error while getting the google_maps dependency on a flutter app

```
Because  app requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because app requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Im currently in version The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-188.5.beta.

does this mean my dart version is not updated?

I solved the problem by downgrading google_maps_flutter but is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: Is there more to the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `sdk` version in `pubspec.yaml` to

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```